# The query has not been defined correctly.. For sub and parallel queries ensure the queries builder is always on the left

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I need one record for each day between dateFrom and dateTo. It should be the first record of the day (in other words, record with min id for each date in date range). So in result i need a list of these records.
I try these code:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<CurrencyConvertionRate> cq = cb.createQuery(CurrencyConvertionRate.class);
    Root<CurrencyConvertionRate> ccrFrom = cq.from(CurrencyConvertionRate.class);
    cq.select(ccrFrom);

    Subquery<Long> subQuery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<CurrencyConvertionRate> from = subQuery.from(CurrencyConvertionRate.class);
    subQuery.select(cb.least(from.<Long>get("id")));
    subQuery.where(
            (cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(from.<Timestamp>get("created"), dateFrom)),
            (cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(from.<Timestamp>get("created"), dateTo)),
            from.get("currencyCode").in(currencyList)
    );
    subQuery.groupBy(from.<Timestamp>get("created"));

    cq.where(cb.in(from.<Long>get("id")).value(subQuery));
    TypedQuery<CurrencyConvertionRate> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
```

And receive exception:

```
 org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException:
 Exception Description: The query has not been defined correctly, the   expression builder is missing.  For sub and parallel queries ensure the queries builder is always on the left.
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=CurrencyConvertionRate )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidBuilderInQuery(QueryException.java:683) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.appendFromClauseToWriter(SQLSelectStatement.java:537) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.printSQL(SQLSelectStatement.java:1621) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar:na]

Exception was thrown: javax.persistence.PersistenceException, Exception [EclipseLink-6121] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The query has not been defined correctly, the expression builder is missing.  For sub and parallel queries ensure the queries builder is always on the left.
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=CurrencyConvertionRate )
An exception has been thrown from an exception mapper class com.lpb.ecom.exception.mapper.RuntimeExceptionMapper.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.lpb.ecom.exception.ExceptionHandler.process(ExceptionHandler.java:115) ~[ecom-lib.jar:na]
    at com.lpb.ecom.exception.ExceptionHandler.getErrorBean(ExceptionHandler.java:71) ~[ecom-lib.jar:na]
    at com.lpb.ecom.exception.mapper.RuntimeExceptionMapper.toResponse(RuntimeExceptionMapper.java:15) ~[ecom-lib.jar:na]
    at com.lpb.ecom.exception.mapper.RuntimeExceptionMapper.toResponse(RuntimeExceptionMapper.java:10) ~[ecom-lib.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.mapException(ServerRuntime.java:396) [jersey-server.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:344) [jersey-server.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:230) [jersey-server.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198) [jersey-server.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946) [jersey-server.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323) [jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372) [jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335) [jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218) [jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) [web-core.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) [web-glue.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260) [web-core.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188) [kernel.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CriteriaBuilder for min id in date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437994/criteriabuilder-for-min-id-in-date-range)

Comment: Not a duplicate, its a new problem

Comment: It is the same question with a different error. if you have made progress then update the original question.